# Weird type syntax in data constructor

Tags: haskell, syntax

I've found some code

```
data Tree c a = Node String [Tree c a]
              | NodeWithCleanup c [Tree c a]
              | Leaf a
```

And I don't understand why it's necessary to add `[Tree c a]`. I don't know this syntax, can you explain it to me ?

Comment: Well it is not necessary, since the `Leaf` case do not has such `[Tree c a]`.

Comment: What specifically about this syntax confuses you? Do you understand anything else here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The list type `[]`

In Haskell lists (which are conceptually *linked list*) are a type `[]`. A list can contain only *one* type of elements (so a list can not contain `Int` and `String`s at the same time).

In case a list thus contains out of elements of type `a`, then we denote this as `[a]`. For example a list of `Int`s is denoted as `[Int]`.

> **Note**: this syntax is actually syntactical sugar. If you write `[a]`, behind the curtains you have actually written `[] a`.

## Types (with type parameters)

In the code fragment you quote, the programmer defines a type `Tree`, and the type has two type parameters `c` (the type of the "cleanup") and `a` (the type of the "leaves"). So that means that a type `Tree c a` is a type for which `c` are the cleanup types and `a` are the leaf types.

If we thus want to construct a list of such `Tree`s, we write `[] (Tree c a)`, or more convenient `[Tree c a]`.

## Data constructors (with parameters)

The programmer has defined three *data constructors*. Data constructors can be seen as labels you attach to objects, and they bind "parameters" together. The number of parameters a data constructor has can differ, as well as the types.

In your code fragment there are three data constructors:

1. `Node` a data constructor that takes two parameters: a `String` and a list of `Tree c a`s (its children);
2. `NodeWithCleanup` a dataconstructor with again two parameters: a `c` (the cleanup) and a list of `Tree c a`s (its children); and
3. `Leaf` a data constructor with a single parameter: the data it stores (of type `a`).

Comment: this is really awesome! I get 4 quality answer for 20 minutes! This iswhy learning haskell a wonderful experience!

Answer (score 3):

Like most “syntax” in Haskell these `[]` aren't really special syntax at all<sup>†</sup>. Constructor declarations simply list the types that are going to be contained. It might become clearer if you add record labels: (I'll diregard the “cleanup” part here)

```
data Tree a
   = Node { nodeCaption :: String
          , subtrees :: [Tree c a] }
   | Leaf { leafContent :: a }
```

This is basically like two Python classes:

```py
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, caption, subs):
      self.nodeCaption = caption
      self.subtrees = subs
class TreeLeaf:
  def __init__(self, content):
      self.leafContent = content
```

...intended to be built like

```py
TreeNode("foo", [TreeNode("bar1", TreeLeaf(1)), TreeNode("bar2", TreeLeaf(2))])
```

In the Haskell implementation, you just write

```
Node "foo" [Node "bar1" (Leaf 1), Node "bar2" (Leaf2)]
```

for that.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Square brackets *are* special syntax in the sense that they are reserved for lists, but the do this the same way no matter if you write them in a function's type signature or in a data declaration.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

When defining a value constructor `K`, the notation `K T1 T2 .. Tn` denotes that `K` is a constructor function taking `n` values, the first one being of type `T1`, and so on.

In `Node String [Tree c a]`, we can see that `Node` takes two arguments. The first is a string (`String`). The second one is a list of trees (`[Tree c a]`). Hence, a node comprises both a string and a list of subtrees.

Instead, `NodeWithCleanup c [Tree c a]` means that a node-with-cleanup comprises a value of type `c` and a list of subtrees.

`Leaf a` means that leafs contain a single value of type `a`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of syntax; it's a matter of semantics. A `Leaf` value just wraps a value of type `a`. The other two constructors wrap lists of `Tree` values, making this a recursive data structure. A `Tree c a` is either a leaf node  (e.g. `Leaf 3`) or an interior node with an arbitrary number of subtrees as children (e.g. `Node "foo" [Leaf 1, Leaf 3, (Node "bar" []]`).